# Base class function not displaying properties

Tags: php, inheritance

i am working on PHP inheritance(just started leraning PHP). I found that base class methods does not display the value of properties when accessed with a child class object. My code look like this.

```
<?php
class Base
{
    public $pr1;
    public $pr2;
    function __construct()
    {
     print "In Base class<br>";    
    }
    public function setPropertie($pr1,$pr2)
    {
         $this->$pr1=$pr1;
         $this->$pr2=$pr2;
    }
    public function display(){
      echo "propertie1".$this->pr1."<br>";
      echo "propertie2".$this->pr2."<br>";

    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        print "Destroying Baseclass<br>";
    }
 }
class Child extends Base
{
     function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
      print "In Subclass<br>";
       }
      function __destruct()
  {
      print "Destroying Subclass<br>";
  }
}
$obj=new Child();
$obj->setPropertie('Abhijith',22);
$obj->display();
?>
```

I can't find what is the problem in the code. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing property incorrectly inside the `setPropertie()` method. Remove `$` from both `$pr1` and `$pr2` property to access them

Wrong way

```
$this->$pr1=$pr1;
$this->$pr2=$pr2;
```

Correct way

```
$this->pr1=$pr1;
$this->pr2=$pr2;
```